# HPA on EKS-Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, hpa

this is not a question about how to implement HPA on a EKS cluster running Fargate pods... It´s about if it is necessary to implement HPA along with Fargate, because as far as I know, Fargate is a "serverless" solution from AWS: "Fargate allocates the right amount of compute, eliminating the need to choose instances and scale cluster capacity. You only pay for the resources required to run your containers, so there is no over-provisioning and paying for additional servers."

So I´m not sure in which cases I would like to implement HPA on an EKS cluster running Fargate but the option is there. So I would like to know if someone could give more information.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EKS/Fargate allows you to NOT run "Cluster Autoscaler" (CA) because there are not nodes you need to run your pods. This is what it is referred to with "no over-provisioning and paying for additional servers."

HOWEVER, you could/would use HPA because Fargate does not provide a resource scaling mechanism for your pods. You can configure [the size of your Faragte pods via K8s requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-pod-configuration.html) but at that point that is a regular pod with finite resources. You can use HPA to determine the number of pods (on Fargate) you need to run at any point in time for your deployment.